# SD Card Transfer very slow

Tags: performance, sd-card

I copied some MySQL-DB stuff to my Class 6 SD card. It needed 45 min. for the transfer. Same machine with XP it does it in a few minutes, with Win7 on another machine transfer is also fine. Checked all the forums and sources but found nothing really related.

Comment: Is this a USB device (reader), or built-in?  can you identify the reader brand/model?  What is the brand/model of the SD-card itself?

Comment: It's built-in and worked fine with the last LTS version[  116.160613] mmc0: new SDHC card at address b368
[  116.162075] mmcblk0: mmc0:b368 00000 30.0 GiB 
[  116.165139]  mmcblk0: p1
[  116.403621] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

Comment: Is Ubuntu up to date?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the default IO scheduler treats these flash drives poorly. One solution that I've found to be useful is to switch the ioscheduler to **deadline** or **noop** for just that device. So for example,

```
$ lsscsi 
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      TOSHIBA THNS128G AGLA  /dev/sda
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GT30N     LT09  /dev/sr0
[7:0:0:0]    disk             Patriot Memory   PMAP  /dev/sdb
```

```
sudo tee /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler << EOF
deadline
EOF
```

```
$ cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler
noop [deadline] cfq
```

and now try your data transfer again, you must do this **before** you load the device.

Should that work for you a udev rule can be created to automatically set this for all usb hotplug devices. Here's one I wrote a long time ago that's a little crufty, I believe it only scans for usb hotplug devices, not MMC cards, so you would have to examine udev output to determine what class your media is in and adjust accordingly.

**PROCEED AT YOUR OWN RISK, IF THIS DOESN'T WORK FOR YOU ITS UP TO YOU TO DEBUG**

```
sudo tee /lib/udev/rules.d/100-usb-scheduler.rules << EOF
# custom udev rule: 28.10.11

# adjust io scheduler for usb block devices: queue/scheduler
# scheme based on "persistent storage rules"

# forward scsi device event to corresponding block device
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="scsi_device", TEST=="block", ATTR{block/*/uevent}="change"

ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="persistent_storage_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="block", GOTO="persistent_storage_end"

# skip rules for inappropriate block devices
KERNEL=="fd*|mtd*|nbd*|gnbd*|btibm*|dm-*|md*", GOTO="persistent_storage_end"

# ignore partitions that span the entire disk
TEST=="whole_disk", GOTO="persistent_storage_end"

# for partitions import parent information
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", IMPORT{parent}="ID_*"

# USB storage devices suffer from performance issues unless they use deadline io scehduler
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", \
        RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo deadline > /sys/$env{DEVPATH}/queue/scheduler'"

LABEL="persistent_storage_end"
EOF
```

```
$ sudo chmod +x /lib/udev/rules.d/100-usb-scheduler.rules
```